# How can I use multiple items in one if statement?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, if-statement

in this case, i'm using:

```
- (IBAction)reset:(id) sender {

if ((boxHide1.hidden = YES) && (boxHide2.hidden = YES)) {
    resetHide.hidden = NO;
}
```

}

How can I do this? I have 12 items all together I need in the statement. Thanks!

Comment: What is it that you need to do?

Comment: i'm making a game, and you must tap all the boxes on the screen. & i want the button that puts more boxes on the screen hidden until all the boxes already there are gone.

Comment: Why don't you use an array with buttons instead of using an instance variable for each button?

Comment: BTW, your `=` in the if statements always return YES, since they are assignments, not comparisons. You should always be using `==` in an if statement, unless you've got a really good reason not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the solution @Joe posted but as you can tell the code for hiding / unhiding could get very messy and hard to read.

If you want to keep your code clean and easy to understand / maintain, I'd put all these buttons into a NSMutableArray and iterate through it to determine whether you want to show the reset button or not.

```
BOOL showResetButton = YES;
for (UIButton *button in buttonsArray)
{
    if (button.hidden == NO) // If any of the buttons is not hidden do not show the reset button
        showResetButton = NO;
}
resetButton.hidden = showResetButton;
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use `==` to compare values but since they are already booleans you do not need to compare against `YES`. If all the comparisons are AND(`&&`) that is correct and you can drop the parenthesis, otherwise if there are any OR(`||`) operations then you would need to group the appropriate operations.

```
if (boxHide1.hidden && 
    boxHide2.hidden && 
    ... &&
    boxHide12.hidden) 
{
    resetHide.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: ah, i used: - (IBAction)reset:(id) sender {
    
    if (boxHide1.hidden && 
        boxHide2.hidden && 
        boxHide3.hidden &&
        boxHide4.hidden &&
        boxHide5.hidden &&
        boxHide6.hidden &&
        boxHide7.hidden &&
        boxHide8.hidden &&
        boxHide9.hidden &&
        boxHide10.hidden &&
        boxHide11.hidden &&
        boxHide12.hidden) {
        
        resetHide.enabled = YES;
    }
}

Comment: @RyanCohen -- I'd suggest you spend more time learning C before you delve much deeper into Objective-C.  If you don't understand Boolean logic then storage management is going to be a [impolite reference].